# Stripe Payment gateway I wants to use amount in decimal format

Tags: stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe Payment gateway (php) in my website. I want to send a subscription amount in decimal form.  For example I'd like to send 9.99 but it gives me an error that it is an invalid integer. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Can you show the code you've used?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All amounts sent to Stripe must be in integers, representing the lowest currency unit (e.g., cents). So your subscription amount would be 999.

Hope that helps,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Comment: thanks for response. I sent this amount 999 but its comes up as 999$ mean to say that subsciption amount charged 999$ instead of 9.99

Comment: @SaeedRehman Are you using Stripe's API directly, or are you using a third-party library?

Comment: If you email in to support at Stripe from the address associated with the account, I can take a look at your logs to see what's happening.

Comment: @LarryUllman May I know why it needs to be integer? All along our ecommerce site works perfectly then all of a sudden some transactions wont go thru. The new currency conversion was valued at 3.125. So now we have amount like (37 * 3.125) * 100. and its no longer whole number.

Comment: @3s2ng Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: @behroozdalvandi sad to say no choice but we need to round up the value. Which should not be the case coz now there is no way we can tally the amount for multi currency.

Comment: I actually manipulated my Stripe extension code to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Amount that you send to Stripe must be in integer (you should send value in cents) but note there is issue with some currencies. See explanation here:
https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal

I use next code for my payment module:

```
<?php

$currency = 'usd';
$amount = 17.24;

if(in_array($currency,['bif','clp','djf','gnf','jpy','kmf','krw']))
{                   
    $amount = number_format(ceil($amount) , 0, '', '');
}
else
{
    $amount = number_format(($amount*100) , 0, '', '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must first multiply by 100, then convert it to an integer.

here an example of python code for payment with decimal with stripe

```py
   amount = int(request.session['total'] * 100)

   # Charge card 
   stripe.Charge.create(
       customer=customer,
           amount=amount,
           currency='eur',
           description="Pizzeria"
       )
```